# Create a SQLite database from only certain columns of a pandas df?

Tags: python, sqlite

I know how to use `to_sql.()` to copy all data from a pandas data-frame to a table in a sqlite database, but how do I create a table in a sqlite database using only certain, selected columns from the pandas data-frame?

TIA.

Comment: How will you copy all the data from dataframe if you create table with only a few columns?

Comment: I don't need all of the data from the dataframe, just a few columns worth of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `list of columns`, and then take only those columns while calling `to_sql`
Something like:

```py
>>df
   a  b  stats
0  1  A      0
1  2  B      1
2  3  C      0
>>import sqlite3
>>conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
>>cols = ['a', 'stats']
>>df[cols].to_sql('newTable', conn)
```

**SQLite Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
cols = ['your', 'desired', 'database', 'columns']

df[cols].to_sql()
```